# removeObserver:forKeyPath: crashes during keyPath notification

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have created an observer to track the "rate" of my AVPlayer. The observer notification is presented each time the AVPlayer rate changes as expected. However, when I try to remove the observer when playback ends on the item that the AVPlayer is playing, I get the following crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <MediaController 0x10181e000> for the key path "rate" from <NSNotificationCenter 0x1740da080> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

This does not make sense because the observer has to be registered in order for me to remove the observer. In other words, the point at which I remove the observer is in the handler for receiving the observer notification. So clearly, the observer is registered. Here is my relevant code to create the observer:

```
 AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:address];
 moviePlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:item];

 [moviePlayer addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"rate"
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:NULL];
```

Then when the item that is playing finishes, the following handler code is executed upon receiving the observer notification:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
    float rate = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] floatValue];
    if (rate == 0.0) {
        // Playback stopped

        if (CMTimeGetSeconds(moviePlayer.currentTime) >=
            CMTimeGetSeconds(moviePlayer.currentItem.duration)) {
            // Playback reached end

            // Remove further notifications until the next time we need the movie player
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate"];
```

Upon execution of removeObserver, the app crash occurs. I have also tried adding a non-null context of &moviePlayer and removing the observer with that context, but it still crashes. I've also tried delaying the removal, but that doesn't solve the problem either.

What am I missing to avoid this crash?

Comment: You can check this link with my answer
[removeObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59438244/10678941)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't register the observer with NSNotificationCenter, but with the `moviePlayer` object.

Try doing:

```
// Remove further notifications until the next time we need the movie player
[moviePlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate"];
```